# UINavigationBar with extra height is not centering elements inside

Tags: ios, resize, height, uinavigationbar, centering

I have a subclass of UINavigationBar and i change its height with:

```
NavigationbarFlat *navbar = (NavigationbarFlat *)[[self navigationController] navigationBar];
CGRect frame = [navbar frame];
frame.origin.y = 20;
frame.size.height = 60.0;
[navbar setFrame : frame];
```

It's works, but the elements inside the navigationBar is not vertically center. The extra space is placed on top. I've tried with autoresizemask and setcontentviewmode, but not lucky.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried setting that `CGRect` as the *`bounds`* as opposed to the *`frame`*?

Comment: Yes, i've tried, same result... As a temporal solution i'am changing every view inside the navigationBar... But it's strange!